# How to define global variables in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform project I am working on. In it, I want a file to contain many variables. I want these variables to be accessible from any module of the project. I have looked in the docs and on a udemy course but still don't see how to do this. How does one do this in terraform? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. There are several discussions about this at Github, but this is not [something the Hashicorp](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/5480#issuecomment-193360862) team wants.

> In general we're against the particular solution of Global Variables, since it makes the input -> resources -> output flow of Modules less explicit, and explicitness is a core design goal.

I know, we have to repeat a lot of variables between different modules

Comment: I just have seen these github discussions. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

For pathing constants between lots of modules we can use the following simple way.

## /modules/global_constants/outputs.tf:

Describe module with global constants as outputs:

```
output "parameter_1" {
  value     = "value_1"
  sensitive = true
}

output "parameter_2" {
  value     = "value_2"
  sensitive = true
}
```

## /example_1.tf

After we can use in any *.tf

```
module "global_settings" {
   source = "./modules/global_constants"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault" {
   name                = module.global_settings.parameter_1
   resource_group_name = module.global_settings.parameter_2
}
```

## /modules/module2/main.tf

Or in other any modules:

```
module "global_settings" {
   source = "../global_constants"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault" {
   name                = module.global_settings.parameter_1
   resource_group_name = module.global_settings.parameter_2
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I try to do this

1. Define a the set of common variables e.g. `common_tags` at the bottom/top of the `variables.tf` file for all modules. Usually, your tech ops admin/cloud admin will have a template project created for this.
2. For each module, I add the following as the last item

   `global_var   = var.global_var_val`

An example is common tags. In any root/child module I combine them using `merge()` function. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-var-file` to pass the overrides. Example:

```bash
terraform -chdir=staging/000base apply -var-file ../../global.tfvars
```

Other way can be dedicated shared module.
For example you have module with:

```
output "my_var" {
  value = "apollo440"
}
```

And in other modules you can use it like:

```
module "gvars" {
  # source = "git@github.com:user/terraform-global-vars.git?ref=v0.0.1-alpha"
  source="../../../modules/global_vars"
}

provider "something" {
  name="${module.gvars.my_var}"
}
```

Third way could be to use https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest/docs/data-sources/http to query some `http` endpoint.

Ouh... and forth way could be to utilize Vault Provider https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs